# Custom Query Param in WSO2 SAML 2.0 Request

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

Can add custom query param with wso2 SAML 2.0 request rather than SAMLRequest,RelayState?
I want to make SAML request with target URL query param to make redirection to target URL after authentication success.
Example :9443/samlsso?SAMLRequest=jZPRb9owE.........&targetURL=home.jsp

Comment: AFAIK the spec doesn't allow other attributes than RelayState. Why you can't use that?

Comment: thanks for ur comment.I thought to use my custom parameter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use any parameter. But only Relaystate will be redirected back to SP.

Answer (score 3):

You can add custom query parameters in to SAML Request... But only the "RelayState" would be redirected back to the service provider by WSO2IS. If you want to redirect to a target URL after authentication success, You must configure it as ACS in the service provider configurations of the WSO2IS.

Comment: thanks Asela,I want to redirect back to SP by WSO2IS.

Comment: Where exactly should I add this parameter? I need to pass a parameter from my application and read it on the WSO2 login page instead.